# Why is my cube projection messed up in one scene but not the other?

Tags: texturing, uv

As the title says, I'm trying to make a new cube and cube projection in my current scene and it just is not working. In a new scene it looks like this: [image]

In my current scene it looks like this: [image]

I'm pretty confused as to whats happening differently between the two scenes. Both are new cubes with no modifiers at all.

(I know I've been asking a lot of questions lately, hope I'm not breaking any rules)

Any suggestions? What factors cause the cube projection to be different between scenes?

Edit: Creation .gif : [image]

Comment: What do you mean by scene? Different files or different render layers?

Comment: Different files. All layers on the odd one act the same way.

Comment: So when you create a new cube on your odd file and look at the UV's it looks like the bottom photo before you've done anything? A completely new untouched cube?

Comment: Correct. Here is a .gif of the process: http://i.imgur.com/9cr1vm1.gif

Comment: @douglasg14b if you are using seams, why do you chose cube projection? that option will ignore your seams.

Comment: I have never done it any other way, some tutorial selected seams and then did a cube projection. Just using knowledge gleamed from tutorials, stack exchange, and the wiki. Chalk it up to being a novice.

Comment: When you use seams select the first option _Unwrap_

Comment: With a cube seams aren't needed, it's a very simple item that can be used with cube projection or smart unwrap. Also Denis, it did take his seams into account, if you don't have seams and click cube project it gives you a different result.

Comment: Actually if I make a new file. Use "Cube Projection" on one cube. Exit edit mode and create a 2nd cube and try the same thing, the Cube Projection for the 2nd cube is messed up in a similar way. Can either of you reproduce that?

Comment: @douglasg14b Yeah it's doing that for me, looking into it at the moment...

Comment: @douglasg14b the only thing that will change cube projection is the location in 3D space and rotation, UVs are ignored.

Comment: @Denis Yeah not sure why it's doing that, cube projection ignores the view angle/placement. And even after applying location, rotation, and scale, it does the same weird thing.

Comment: @meed96 That's what is supposed to do, it's not an error.

Comment: Then how in the world are you supposed to quick and easy unwrap a cube with cube projection unless that cube happens to be at the center of the world?

Comment: He seems to be right, that is the way it works. I'm not sure if it's intentionally setup that way or not though.

Answer (score 2):

Cube projection will project the mesh from 6 view directions ignoring the seams, and depends where the mesh located in 3D space and its rotation, UVs position will be calculated in UV/Image Editor.

> Blender offers several ways of mapping UVs. The simpler projection
>   methods use formulas that map 3d space onto 2d space, by interpolating
>   the position of points toward a point/axis/plane through a surface.
>   The more advanced methods can be used with more complex models, and
>   have more specific uses.

[UV Mapping a Mesh](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/textures/mapping/uv/unwrapping.html?highlight=cube%20projection#mapping-types)

Comment: Hi, is there any way to define the pivot for the cube projection?

Answer (score 1):

To unwrap a cube there are a few options.
Mark the seams like this and unwrap:
[image]

Other way with no seams is to select a face to make it active, then select all of them with <kbd>A</kbd> and unwrap with follow active quads:

[image]